# Insert dynamic HTML block in product description

Tags: magento-1.9, backend

I would like to give my client the ability, in the backend, to insert in the product description some HTML blocks which have their classes and formatted style. My client has no knowledge of HTML and CSS, so I would like to give him the possibility to write just a short code to be parsed in the frontend to render the appropriate HTML.

The block i want to render is this:

```
    <p class="mb20">
        <span class="label">{label}</span>
        <span class="value">{value}</span>
    </p>
```

the {label} and {value} should be replaced by the values specified in the shortcode my client should write in the product description:

```
[custom_block label="My label" value="My Value"]
```

Does Magento provide such a similar functionality or should I write something on my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO this is an ideal case for widgets:

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-1

Alan Storm's book, No-Frills Magento Layout, has an excellent chapter on building new and extending existing widgets:

> http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout

(But beware that adding custom content on a widget directive -- like text with double quotes -- can create a bug in how magento passes that information to the block: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23925826/1442685)

Or as an alternative, writing your own directive:

> http://de.nr-apps.com/blog/2013/04/11/custom-e-mail-template-directives/

---

If you were to take the widget approach, then your directive might look like this:

```
{{widget type="yourmodule/widget" label="<p>Some Label</p>" value="And a value"}}
```

Which, in your widget's template is accessible on the block via internal data store:

```
$this->getLabel() // <p>Some Label</p>
```

Comment: ...and i'm seconds too late, deleting my similar answer for a more thorough one. :)

Comment: At least the second doctor's opinion was the same :)